# Changing scene in another class method JavaFX

Tags: javafx, scene, stage

I'm new to JavaFX. I'm trying to change scene in my first project and I'm wondering if I can do it like that:

```
public class A {
        ...
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            ...
        B ObjectB = new B();
        Scene scene = new Scene();
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            ...
        if (...) {
            ObjectB.anotherFunction(primaryStage);
        }
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

public class B {
        ...
    public void anotherFunction(Stage stage) {
            ...
        Scene NewScene = new Scene();
        stage.setScene(NewScene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Code above is shortened version of what I wrote. 
I want to change scene from one class that is like menu class (A) in other class (B) and display new scene on the screen. It seems like it's not possible in the way I did it and I'm curious what are good practices in that kind of things.

Comment: are your if condition "true" at the start of your program?

Comment: At the beginning it's false, and then it's true. I want my program first to display scene and then NewScene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It`s works. For example just try simply call

```
  ObjectB.anotherFunction(primaryStage);
```

after or before your

```
primaryStage.show();
```

method. Your problem here is that you check this "if" once, even before showing this stage and it false at the start, and then, when it comes true - this piece of code already passed. You just need to run `ObjectB.anotherFunction(primaryStage);`, when set condition of your if to true.

PS. and pls, start name of your variables from a small letter, objectB instead of ObjectB - it`s just a Java Naming Convention.